# Replacing nth substring occurrence from a String in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Im trying to make a predicate that replaces the nth substring occurrence from a String like this.

```
replace_word(word, nthOcurrence, toReplace, replaceWith , Result)
```

So if i call `replace_word(zXyyyzXyyXzX, 2, zX, OO , Result)` i could get

`Result = zXyyyOOyyXzX`

I tried to implement this utility

```
replace_word(Old, New, Orig, Replaced) :-
atomic_list_concat(Split, Old, Orig),
atomic_list_concat(Split, New, Replaced).
```

But it replaces all ocurrences. 
any hint is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recently added [call_nth](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call_nth/2)/2, together with the flexible ISO predicate [sub_atom](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sub_atom/5)/5, allows for a clean implementation:

```
replace_nth_word(Word,NthOcurrence,ToReplace,ReplaceWith,Result) :-
    call_nth(sub_atom(Word,Before,_Len,After,ToReplace),NthOcurrence),
    sub_atom(Word,0,Before,_,Left), % get left part
    sub_atom(Word,_,After,0,Right), % get right part
    atomic_list_concat([Left,ReplaceWith,Right],Result).
```

Apparently, it works for **strings** also, thanks to the extended representation of literals implemented in SWI-Prolog from version 7.